# Expected an identifier and instead saw '*' line 7 pos 3

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, sublimetext3, jslint

I am trying to merge the coins into master but there is a conflict. I am unable to save the game.js file either because sublime is yelling at me for having a syntax error that I can't figure out, please help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTeFN.png)

here is all the code with bugs as per sublime text 3:

```
// Canvas Asteroids
//
// Copyright (c) 2010 Doug McInnes
//

KEY_CODES = {
  '32': 'space',
  '37': 'left',
  '38': 'up',
  '39': 'right',
  '40': 'down',
  '70': 'f',
  '71': 'g',
  '72': 'h',
  '77': 'm',
  '80': 'p'
}

KEY_STATUS = { keyDown:false };
for (code in KEY_CODES) {
  KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[code]] = false;
}

$(window).keydown(function (e) {
  KEY_STATUS.keyDown = true;
  if (KEY_CODES[e.keyCode]) {
    e.preventDefault();
    KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[e.keyCode]] = true;
  }
}).keyup(function (e) {
  KEY_STATUS.keyDown = false;
  if (KEY_CODES[e.keyCode]) {
    e.preventDefault();
    KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[e.keyCode]] = false;
  }
});

GRID_SIZE = 60;

Matrix = function (rows, columns) {
  var i, j;
  this.data = new Array(rows);
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    this.data[i] = new Array(columns);
  }

  this.configure = function (rot, scale, transx, transy) {
    var rad = (rot * Math.PI)/180;
    var sin = Math.sin(rad) * scale;
    var cos = Math.cos(rad) * scale;
    this.set(cos, -sin, transx,
             sin,  cos, transy);
  };

  this.set = function () {
    var k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        this.data[i][j] = arguments[k];
        k++;
      }
    }
  }

  this.multiply = function () {
    var vector = new Array(rows);
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      vector[i] = 0;
      for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        vector[i] += this.data[i][j] * arguments[j];
      }
    }
    return vector;
  };
};

Sprite = function () {
  this.init = function (name, points) {
    this.name     = name;
    this.points   = points;

    this.vel = {
      x:   0,
      y:   0,
      rot: 0
    };

    this.acc = {
      x:   0,
      y:   0,
      rot: 0
    };
  };

  this.children = {};

  this.color    = 'black';
  this.solid    = false;
  this.visible  = false;
  this.reap     = false;
  this.bridgesH = true;
  this.bridgesV = true;

  this.collidesWith = [];

  this.x     = 0;
  this.y     = 0;
  this.rot   = 0;
  this.scale = 1;

  this.currentNode = null;
  this.nextSprite  = null;

  this.preMove  = null;
  this.postMove = null;

  this.run = function(delta) {

    this.move(delta);
    this.updateGrid();

    this.context.save();
    this.configureTransform();
    this.draw();

    var canidates = this.findCollisionCanidates();

    this.matrix.configure(this.rot, this.scale, this.x, this.y);
    this.checkCollisionsAgainst(canidates);

    this.context.restore();

    if (this.bridgesH && this.currentNode && this.currentNode.dupe.horizontal) {
      this.x += this.currentNode.dupe.horizontal;
      this.context.save();
      this.configureTransform();
      this.draw();
      this.checkCollisionsAgainst(canidates);
      this.context.restore();
      if (this.currentNode) {
        this.x -= this.currentNode.dupe.horizontal;
      }
    }
    if (this.bridgesV && this.currentNode && this.currentNode.dupe.vertical) {
      this.y += this.currentNode.dupe.vertical;
      this.context.save();
      this.configureTransform();
      this.draw();
      this.checkCollisionsAgainst(canidates);
      this.context.restore();
      if (this.currentNode) {
        this.y -= this.currentNode.dupe.vertical;
      }
    }
    if (this.bridgesH && this.bridgesV &&
        this.currentNode &&
        this.currentNode.dupe.vertical &&
        this.currentNode.dupe.horizontal) {
      this.x += this.currentNode.dupe.horizontal;
      this.y += this.currentNode.dupe.vertical;
      this.context.save();
      this.configureTransform();
      this.draw();
      this.checkCollisionsAgainst(canidates);
      this.context.restore();
      if (this.currentNode) {
        this.x -= this.currentNode.dupe.horizontal;
        this.y -= this.currentNode.dupe.vertical;
      }
    }
  };
  this.move = function (delta) {
    if (!this.visible) return;
    this.transPoints = null; // clear cached points

    if ($.isFunction(this.preMove)) {
      this.preMove(delta);
    }
```

Comment: You're asking two separate questions. Fix the syntax error first.

Comment: Please include the code as text in your question. Images of code are discouraged.

Comment: Everything was fine yesterday but I had customized my sublime text 3 editor and added a bunch of packages. JSlint ESlint and so on. Now I ran into more issues please see the code below:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@torazaburo Thank you, you are right. JSLint was the problem all worked when I removed the package from Sublime Text 3.

@torazaburo

> should work identically as property names. This seems to be a bug in
>   JSLint, which is notoriously picky.